# Pytorch: Correctly reshape columns into matricies

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I am having trouble in correctly reshaping theese columns obtained from the multiplication of a sparse matrix and the input. For example, let's say I have the following sparse matrix with the following shape:
`torch.Size([2,972])` and an input vector of shape: `torch.Size([108, 2])`, by transponsing the input vector and doing to dot product I obtain a tensor A of size `torch.Size([2, 9, 2]))` defined as the following:

```
tensor([[[ 34480,  49811],
         [ 62672,  72119],
         [ 49617, 129834],
         [ 58862,  69061],
         [209598, 165029],
         [157133, 144929],
         [ 86957,  91814],
         [205047, 228574],
         [230294, 144340]],

        [[ 31880,  73623],
         [ 73641, 150267],
         [ 91390, 112184],
         [ 56916,  72953],
         [227125, 192221],
         [145567, 110968],
         [ 83470,  77461],
         [203651, 246334],
         [258275, 117184]]]),

tensor.Size([2,9,2])
```

Now what I would like to do is to reshape A as a tensor of size (2,2,3,3) as the following:

```
tensor([[[[ 34480,  62672,  49617],
          [ 58862, 209598, 157133],
          [ 86957, 205047, 230294]],

         [[ 31880,  73641,  91390],
          [ 56916, 227125, 145567],
          [ 83470, 203651, 258275]]]])
tensor([[[[ 49811,  72119, 129834],
          [ 69061, 165029, 144929],
          [ 91814, 228574, 144340]],

         [[ 73623, 150267, 112184],
          [ 72953, 192221, 110968],
          [ 77461, 246334, 117184]]]])
```

But doing A.reshape(2,2,3,3) I obtain this instead:

```
tensor([[[[ 34480,  49811,  62672],
          [ 72119,  49617, 129834],
          [ 58862,  69061, 209598]],

         [[165029, 157133, 144929],
          [ 86957,  91814, 205047],
          [228574, 230294, 144340]]],


        [[[ 31880,  73623,  73641],
          [150267,  91390, 112184],
          [ 56916,  72953, 227125]],

         [[192221, 145567, 110968],
          [ 83470,  77461, 203651],
          [246334, 258275, 117184]]]]))
```

How can I reshape A correctly?

Comment: You will have to do some transpositions before reshaping.
`A.transpose(-2, -1).transpose(-3,-2).reshape(2,2,3,3)` worked for me, but there is probably a better way.
Cheers

Comment: Instead of transposing twice, you can use `permute`: `A.permute(2, 0, 1).reshape(2, 2, 3, 3)`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the solution! I just need to understand a little bit why it needs to be permuted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A very special thanks to [@Chrysophylaxs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9499196/chrysophylaxs) for resolving my issue, I'll repost his comment here:

> Instead of transposing twice, you can use `permute`: `A.permute(2, 0, 1).reshape(2, 2, 3, 3).`

Cheers and keep coding!